# Cannot retrieve values of objects AsyncStorage using Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an object in my AsyncStorage. Problem is, the object is returned by rendering, but values only by clicking on Button.

Peace of code MainScreen.js

```
const { state, retrieveUser } = useContext(User);

useEffect(()=>{
   retrieveUser();
 }, [])

 console.log(state.user) // <- Return object
 console.log(state.user.name) // <- Return TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.user.name')

<Button 
    title="Retrieve Name" 
    onPress={()=>{console.log(state.user.name)}} // <- Return "John"
 />
```

`console.log(state.user)` in Main.js returns object:

```
Object {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John",
  "age": "20"
}
```

`console.log(state.user.name)` returns *"TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.user.name')"*

But

**By clicking on button on this screen** **with** `onPress={()=>console.log(state.user.name)}` **it returns "John".**

Peace of code ContextApi.js:

```
const userReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'retrieve_user':
            return { user: action.payload };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};

const retrieveUser = dispatch => async () => {
    const accountData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    let user = JSON.parse(accountData);
    dispatch({ type: 'retrieve_user', payload: user});
};
```

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `initial user data` in your reducer is undefined.

```
// default state is undefined
const userReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'retrieve_user':
            return { user: action.payload };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};
```

When you call `retrieveUser` in your useEffect, this function will be called as `componentDidMount`. So in the first time of render, your `user data` still is undefined.

Try to check like this:

```
state.user && console.log(state.user.name)
```

**EDIT**

If you want to render multi keys depend on `state.user`, try to like this:

```
state.user && (
   <Text>{state.user.name}</Text>
   <Text>{state.user.age}</Text>
   <Text>{state.user...}</Text>
)
```

Comment: console.log() works, thanks! But how to render it, for example ```<Text>{state.user.name}</Text>``` doesn't work. In my export of ContextApi i declared ```{ user: {} }```. I also tried in useReducer ```return { ...state, user: action.payload }```

Comment: I should each element wrap like so? ```{state.user && <Text>{state.user.name}</Text>}```, ```{state.user && <Text>{state.user.age}</Text>}``` and so on?

Comment: Because those values depend on `state.user`. So, I think you should check `state.user` is not undefined, then render `name, age and so on`. Check my edit code